# Метод штрафных функций

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика

Привет!

Пытаюсь реализовать метод штрафных функций для вычисления минимума функции. Ищу минимум функции Розенброка, минимизирую с помощью внешних штрафных функций:
[image]
[image]

придумав свои ограничения. Сначала использую встроенную `scipy.optimize.minimize`:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen
rz = lambda x: (1-x[0])**2 + 100*(x[1] - x[0]**2)**2;
h_1 = lambda x: (x[0] - 2 * x[1] + 2);
h_2 = lambda x: (-x[0] - 2 * x[1] + 6);
h_3 = lambda x: (-x[0] + 2 * x[1] + 2);

x0 = [2.3, 5];
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': h_1},
       {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': h_2},
       {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': h_3}) 
minimize(rz, x0, constraints=cons)
```

Которая даёт ответ: `x: array([ 0.99971613,  0.99942073])`

Затем пытаюсь реализовать метод штрафных функций:

```
x_c = [2.3, 3];
i = 1;
while i < 1000:
    curr_func = lambda x: rz(x) + i*(h_1(x)**2 + h_2(x)**2 + h_3(x)**2)
    x_c = minimize(curr_func, x_c).x;
    i  *= 1.2;
print(answer.x);
```

Что выводит мне `[ 2.27402022  1.4157964 ]` (если увеличивать количество итераций, точка будет ещё с большими координатами).

Где я ошибаюсь в реализации?
Спасибо.

P.S. Окончательная функция `curr_func` специфична для конкретно приведённых ограничений, конечно, когда все они типа `inequals`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не всегда увеличение количества итераций даст лучший результат, особенно в методах оптимизации. Как правило крутить надо параметры, которые отвечают за штраф или начальные точки, если конечно правильно реализован алгоритм. Еще один момент - надо задать точность результата, и из цикла лучше все-таки выходить, когда результат достигнет точности.

Я поправил ваш алгоритм, пользуясь [этой](http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%88%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9) статьей

```
 x_c = [2.3, 3]
 i = 1
 r = 1
 b = 0.2
 eps = 0.01
 while i < 1000:
     if curr_func(x_c) < eps:
         break
     curr_func = lambda x: rz(x) + r*(1.0/(h_1(x)**2 + h_2(x)**2 + h_3(x)**2))
     x_c = minimize(curr_func, x_c).x;
     i += 1
     r  *= b;
print(x_c)
print(i)
[ 0.99495003  0.98991398]
3
```

получаем результат всего за 3 итерации.